Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with 6.5.0-45-generic kernel and nvidia 555 driver hangs on boot
I can see there are some related problems reported, but none of the solutions work for me.
The problem: hang on boot
History: The system is fully patched and nvidia 555 was working fine until last week. After a GNOME update, several issues occurred simultaneously:

The battery was reported as "not charging," but the laptop still ran on battery.
It started switching off irregularly on battery power, without a consistent battery level.
One morning, it hung on boot and has been unfixable since.

All hardware tests show no errors.
I've discovered an ACPI error reported as a BIOS bug, but it does not seem to be the problem. I've tried all older driver versions back to 454 without success - all hang on boot.
Additionally, I can run Ctrl+Alt+F2 and then nvidia-bug-report.sh and nvidia-smi. Both work fine.
Only the gdm fails to load just before the login screen appears. Can't use any nvidia driver only nouveau
The only meaningful error found sofar is in the nvidia-bug-report.log - signature and/or required key missing :
[    3.490857] hid-multitouch 0018:2808:0102.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [FTCS1000:01 2808:0102] on i2c-FTCS1000:01
[    3.560664] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.560672] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    3.560673] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint

[    3.560675] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

[    3.560675] nvidia: module license taints kernel.
[    3.688897] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510

[    3.690179] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0100 -> 0103)
[    3.698777] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none

Here is some technical info:
$ inxi -SG 
System:
  Host: laptopWithLinux Kernel: 6.5.0-45-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.9 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] driver: nouveau
    v: kernel
  Device-3: Chicony USB2.0 Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 2560x1600
  OpenGL: renderer: NV176 v: 4.3 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2


Any ideas and help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I found this thread  related to the 550 driver with a lot of suggestions. Unfortunately, none of them worked for me, but I believe someone may find something useful.

EDIT 7 Aug 2024:
Here are some log messages that look like a hint:
/var/log/dmesg.0:[    2.425820] kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.                              │
/var/log/dmesg.0:[    2.425827] kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.                                 │
/var/log/dmesg.0:[    2.425828] kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint                                   │
/var/log/dmesg.0:[    2.425830] kernel: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tai│
nting kernel                                                                                                           │
/var/log/dmesg.0:[    2.425831] kernel: nvidia: module license taints kernel.                                          │
/var/log/dmesg.0:[    4.522197] kernel: nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietar│
y module nvidia, inheriting taint.  

it is from the latest 555 driver
these lines appear each time nvidia driver installation attempt since 23 Jul 2024

EDIT 9 Aug 2024
With invaluable help from @nobody and hours of investigation, here is the current state:
[    24.617] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    24.617] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    24.671] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    24.671] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied

also:
$ ls /sys/firmware/
acpi  dmi  efi  memmap

$ sudo mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled

Now, the question is why Gnome/Xorg can't find it.

EDIT 10 Aug 2024
The additional scrutiny added these:

SecureBoot is disabled;
(U)EFI is used
kernel has CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y, but CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE is not set
NVIDIA module is indeed signed with sha512 which is required by the kernel
in system log there is a record: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing

Attempt to install via *.run failed as well. The nvidia install log is available here

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Well, this was quite an adventure with a lot of nerves thorn apart, but with a happy end.
First of all, I'd like to thank @nobody for the time spent and his incredible help. All credits go to him.
Before ending up with the solutions a lot of actions had been taken - installing/uninstalling, cleaning & deleting, again and again...
The summary that solved the problem is:

Clean everything related to the previous Nvidia driver installation. This step itself can vary from system to system, so be thorough.

Check your .bashrc and comment out everything related to Nvidia and CUDA. I had these lines:


export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-12.4/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-12.4/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}


Once all Nvidia resources are removed, install the driver. I used:

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535


Make Nvidia the primary resource:

sudo prime-select nvidia


reboot

Conclusion: One of the biggest mistakes I made was relying on autoclean and purge. While they are usually handy, they were powerless after the mess I had created. So, DIY—search and clean manually.
